# my CSS classes collide with each other despite of having different name but similarities

Tags: css, css-selectors

for example `.create-post-heading` class collides with class `create-post-heading heading`
though there are two classes `create-post-heading` and `heading` but I don't know which one collides with which one like

[image]

in the above image when I add CSS to the `.create-post-heading` class my div having those two classes also inherit those properties but how?

Comment: Can you kindly create a code snippet? Just click the edit button, then press Ctrl M.

Comment: What do you mean by *"when I add css to .create-post-heading class my div having those two classes also inherite that properties"* ? If you add a property, it's normal for that property being applied, no matter how much classes your div has.